# Injectivity radius of leaves of a foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary, one obtains a foliation of the normal collar into a collection of hypersurfaces $M^t$ which for each $t$ are defined as the hypersurface of points distance $t$ from the boundary. In this case $M^0=\partial M$ is the boundary.

Is there a way to relate the injectivity radius of each of these hypersurfaces to the injectivity radius of the boundary?

More generally, if $M$ is not compact with uniform normal collar, does positive injectivity radius of $\partial M$ imply positive injectivity radius of each $M^t$

Comment: I don't have an answer, but especially for the not compact case you might find some useful information in "Manifolds with boundary and of bounded geometry" by Thomas Schick, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/1522-2616%28200103%29223%3A1%3C103%3A%3AAID-MANA103%3E3.0.CO%3B2-S